# Is the phrase "...could only know by then" correct?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

> He told me he would give me the answer after the trip. Was there
>   something he **could only know by then**?

I don't know why but it sounds a little weird to me. Anyway, to make sure I [searched](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1225&bih=807&q=%22could%20only%20know%20by%20then%20%22&oq=%22could%20only%20know%20by%20then%20%22&gs_l=serp.3...3358.3776.0.3974.6.5.0.0.0.2.138.392.0j3.3.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..6.0.0.vtVsO-8YBrM) on Google. As you can see, there's only **1** result.

Did I misspell something? Or use a wrong word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent phrase that is more idiomatic ([Google says about 14,000,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=will%20not%20know%20until%20then&oq=will%20not%20know%20until%20then&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22won%27t%20know%20until%20then%22)) is "*won't know until then*", for example:

[*So Help Me God* By Larry D. Thompson](http://books.google.com/books?id=JHfnLQ-iecUC&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> She hasn't regained consciousness.  I think we have the right antibiotics for now.  We won't have the blood culture results back until at least tomorrow morning.  It may be that there is another antibiotic that will be more effective to fight the infection.  **We won't know until then**.

So consider this wording instead

> He told me he would give me the answer after the trip. Was there something he **wouldn't know until then**?

A Google search for "wouldn't know until then" [yields about 11,200,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=will%20not%20know%20until%20then&oq=will%20not%20know%20until%20then&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22wouldn%27t%20know%20until%20then%22).

Comment: But can I still use won't if the passage is in the past tense?

Comment: @janoChen, good point, perhaps "Was there something he wouldn't know until then?"  --- Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to "could have" (which is appropriate for other contexts - they are not equivalent), "could," while correct, has a much more limited use in **past time** contexts.

Many times you'll find replaced, when the past time is involved, as in:

1. *I **could** do the job [then].*

by

2. *I **was able** to do the job [then].*

This is what makes it quite rare, and makes us feel it awkward at times.

One important reason is removing the potential parsing uncertainty wrt time in the mind of the reader, created because the **modal/subjunctive mood** "could" is very frequently used in **present time**:

3. *Yes, I guess I **could** do the job [right now].*

This time ambiguity is of course smaller when appropriate adverbials are used, still the users are wary about it.

However, there's no such reduction in past time use for "would," thus go for:

*Was there something he **would** only know by then?*

in this case.

A further important limitation on *can/could*, which practically proscribes 1 is described in the following very interesting reference:

> An important point here is that *could* (like *can*) does not  suggest
>   that the action was carried out but **only that the possibility was
>   there**. In fact, it is seldom used with a specific action except in
>   the negative, **for it would suggest that the action did not take
>   place**. If the event did in fact happen, we would not use *could* but
>   *did*. This is why we do not say *‘I could have a good T time at their party yesterday’ if a good time was had. Rather we would use a factual
>   statement, ‘I had a good time at their party’, showing that the
>   speaker **both could and did** have a good time.
>
> Although *to be able to* is a fairly accurate paraphrase of *can* in
>   most circumstances, using it to describe a past action uncovers a
>   clear difference; **‘was able to do X’ implies that X was done though
>   with some effort probably, while ‘could do X' says only that it was
>   possible, and with a specific action, implies that X was not done.**
>
> [Realms of Meaning: An Introduction to Semantics](https://books.google.com/books?id=8MOOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false)  By Th. R.
>   Hofmann

Other references on this issue can be obtained with this Google Books search:

[**"could" "was able to" "past time"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22could%22%20%22was%20able%20to%22%20%22past%20time%22&ei=1OowVYfsO6OSsQSfnoGIAw)